# Qt3D default uniform and attributes

Tags: c++, qt, qml, shader

I began to learn using shaders with QML, and I can't find any references that talk about default uniform and attribute values that are passed to the shaders. In certain examples, we can saw several of them like ***vertexPosition*** or ***modelViewProjection*** (that is also passed as ***mvp***), but there is no clear list containing all the variables that we can use.

After investigating in Qt source code, I found out default name for many variables:

1. uniform variables (found in *renderview.cpp*)

   - modelMatrix
   - viewMatrix
   - projectionMatrix
   - modelView
   - viewProjectionMatrix
   - modelViewProjection
   - mvp
   - inverseModelMatrix
   - inverseViewMatrix
   - inverseProjectionMatrix
   - inverseModelView
   - inverseViewProjectionMatrix
   - inverseModelViewProjection
   - modelNormalMatrix
   - modelViewNormal
   - viewportMatrix
   - inverseViewportMatrix
   - exposure
   - gamma
   - time
   - eyePosition
2. attributes (found in *qattribute.cpp*)

   - vertexPosition
   - vertexNormal
   - vertexColor
   - vertexTexCoord
   - vertexTangent

Is that all? These variables are largely sufficient to develop most oh the shaders I am doing right now, but I just want to know if I miss something.

Comment: The same results here. I couldn't find the documentation so turned to the source. I am not sure, but I think that's all. Fortunately, the variable names are somewhat verbose.
https://github.com/qt/qt3d/blob/5.9.0/src/render/backend/renderview.cpp
https://github.com/qt/qt3d/blob/5.9.0/src/render/geometry/qattribute.cpp

Comment: According to this blog post: https://www.kdab.com/shadow-mapping-qt3d-2-0/ and the author's answer at the bottom, that should be it.

Answer (score 3):

to confirm part of what  @aRaMinet said 
source [Qt Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt3d-render-shaderprogram.html)

[image]