# Qt3D Can I list all vertexes from Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer?

Tags: c++, qt, qt3d

e.g.

```
    Qt3DCore::QEntity *sphereEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(rootEntity);
    Qt3DExtras::QSphereMesh *sphereMesh = new Qt3DExtras::QSphereMesh;
    sphereMesh->setRadius(3);

    Qt3DCore::QTransform *sphereTransform = new Qt3DCore::QTransform;
    sphereTransform->setScale(3);

    sphereEntity->addComponent(sphereMesh);
    sphereEntity->addComponent(sphereTransform);
```

Can I get all **sphereMesh**'s vertexes ?

And are it's vertexes tranformed by **sphereTransform** ?

or How can I get the tranformed vertexes ?

I think I can use QAttribute, but I need some examples.

---

update:

### I have tried:

```
    // plane
    Qt3DCore::QEntity *planeEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(rootEntity);
    Qt3DExtras::QPlaneMesh *planeMesh = new Qt3DExtras::QPlaneMesh;
    planeMesh->setWidth(1);
    planeMesh->setHeight(1);

    Qt3DCore::QTransform *planeform = new Qt3DCore::QTransform;
    planeform->setRotation(QQuaternion::fromAxisAndAngle(QVector3D(1, 0, 0), 90.0f));
    planeform->setScale(10);
    planeEntity->addComponent(planeMesh);
    planeEntity->addComponent(material);
    planeEntity->addComponent(planeform);

    // ----------------

    QList<QVector4D> list;
    for ( auto attribute : planeMesh->geometry()->attributes() ) {
        if (attribute->name() == Qt3DRender::QAttribute::defaultPositionAttributeName()) {
            Qt3DRender::QBuffer *buffer = attribute->buffer();

            const QByteArray &data = buffer->data();
            for ( int i = 0 ; i < attribute->count() ; i++ ) {
                int vertexOffset = i * attribute->byteStride();
                int offset = vertexOffset + attribute->byteOffset();


                const char *vertexData = attribute->buffer()->data().constData() + (i * attribute->byteStride() + attribute->byteOffset());
                qDebug() << (int)vertexData;
                const float *typedVertexData = reinterpret_cast<const float*>(vertexData);
                list << QVector4D(typedVertexData[0], typedVertexData[1], typedVertexData[2], 1.0) ;

                qDebug() << list.last();

            } // for
        } // if
    } // for
```

and it's output:

```
QVector4D(0, 0, 0, 1)
QVector4D(1.57402e-38, 1.34525e-43, 0, 1)
QVector4D(0, 7.00649e-45, 1.52015e-23, 1)
QVector4D(1.52015e-23, 0, 0, 1)
```

and I transform it :

```
    qDebug() << (list[0] * planeform->matrix());
    qDebug() << (list[1] * planeform->matrix());
    qDebug() << (list[2] * planeform->matrix());
    qDebug() << (list[3] * planeform->matrix());
    // ---- output --------
    QVector4D(0, 0, 0, 1)
    QVector4D(1.57402e-37, 0, -1.34525e-42, 1)
    QVector4D(0, 1.52015e-22, 9.06081e-30, 1)
    QVector4D(1.52015e-22, 0, 0, 1)
```

I think it is too small. How do I fix it?

Comment: You may have a look into the Qt3d implementation of GLTF export `qt5/qt3d/src/plugins/sceneparsers/gltfexport/gltfexporter.cpp` how the data is exported for general meshes with unknown mesh type, i.e. `meshInfo.meshType == TypeNone`

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question:

`QSphereMesh` is an instance of [`QGeometryRenderer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drender-qgeometryrenderer.html). QGeometryRenderer has a function `geometry()` which returns the respective [`QGeometry`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drender-qgeometry.html). `QGeometry` in turn has a function `attributes()` which returns a vector of the stored attributes (vertices, normals, indices, etc.). You can iterate over this vector of attributes and check the `name()` of the attribute, i.e. whether it is equal to `QAttribute::defaultPositionAttributeName()`. This (I think at least) returns the default name for the vertex attribute used by Qt3D ready-made meshes. You can then use the other functions of `QAttribute` like `byteStride()`, `count()`, etc. to reconstruct the actual vertices (look for something like "QByteArray to array of X" where X is the data type of the buffer of the attribute).

Regarding your second question:

No, the vertices won't be transformed. Qt3D constructs a `modelView` matrix for you and adds it to the shader - which means you can use e.g. `modelView` in your custom shader without having to manually add it. Checkout [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45858370/qt3d-default-uniform-and-attributes) of variables and uniforms that Qt3D adds automatically. You could put the values for each vertex into a `QVector4D` where the last number is a `1` (like e.g. `(0.1, 5.4, 13.2, 1.0)`) and multiply it with the matrix you can get from the transform: `transform->matrix()`. I think you have to multiply the matrix from the right which is a bit counter intuitive: `vector x matrix`.

Comment: I update the code I have tried, but it looks like wrong.

Comment: Hm weird, looking from the code it should work... I just tried to get it to run and it seems that the byte array has size 0. You can check this by calling `attribute->buffer()->data().size()`. Maybe try to populate an attribute yourself manually and then check if the size is also 0. I don't have time to look further into this issue right now unfortunately.

Comment: Wow, `attribute->buffer()->data().size()`'s value is **0**. But... I think it should have data... How amazing..

Comment: Yes exactly, maybe try to manually create an attribute and see what happens when you call `size()` there. I saw a post claiming that you have to `syncData` to `true` on the buffer but that only works for data generators which generate data on the fly but we don't have that here...